# how to read and change a mysql 5 field

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I'm a noob with databases and mysql, I have a mysql database including this table:

```
+----+------------+------------+----------+----------+
| id | day        | start_hour | end_hour | prenoted |
+----+------------+------------+----------+----------+
| 1  | 2020-01-01 | 00:00:00   | 00:01:00 | 0        |
+----+------------+------------+----------+----------+
| 2  | 2020-01-01 | 00:01:00   | 00:02:00 | 0        |
+----+------------+------------+----------+----------+
| 3  | 2020-01-01 | 00:02:00   | 00:03:00 | 0        |
+----+------------+------------+----------+----------+
```

And this is how mysql describes the table:

```
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type    | NULL | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id         | double  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| day        | date    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| start_hour | time(6) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| end_hour   | time(6) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| prenoted   | int(1)  | NO   |     | 0       |       |
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

What I would like to do is:

1)change the prenoted field of my 3rd id from 0 to 1.
 Ithink it should be something like:

```
UPDATE tablename SET prenoted WHERE id=3;
```

But I get syntax error.

2)see from mysql command line if it changed or not.

Thanks in andvance!

(I use mysql 5.7)

Edit: this is a Demo of my table [DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=bb513b295d2a2549931979866856bf8b)

Comment: @Strawberry Because I have 10 000 ids

Comment: @Strawberry sorry, I've added a DBFiddle Demo

Comment: @Strawberry I've updated, now it is

Comment: @Strawberry I'm really sorry, I've updated my question, is it ok now? The DB Fiddle demo provided is the code I use to create my table

Comment: Wow.  Unrelated to your question, but do change id to int not null and make it a primary key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Strawberry that lead me to this answer.
I'm not good in sql so I made a java program that creates an sql file with all days of the year:

```
String[] times = {"00:00:00", "00:01:00", "00:02:00", "00:03:00", "00:04:00", "00:05:00", "00:06:00", "00:07:00",
             "00:08:00", "00:09:00", "00:10:00", "00:11:00", "00:12:00", "00:13:00", "00:14:00", "00:15:00",
             "00:16:00", "00:17:00", "00:18:00", "00:19:00", "00:20:00", "00:21:00", "00:22:00", "00:23:00"};

for(int j=1; j<=mothDays; j++) {
            if(j<10) day = "0" + j;
            else day = "" + j;
            for(int k=0; k<24; k++) {   //one for each prenotable hour
                id++;
                try {
                    if(k == 23) {
                        writer.write(System.getProperty("line.separator") + "(" + id + ",'2020-" + month + "-" + day + 
                                "','" + times[k] + "','" + times[0] + "',0),");
                    }else {
                        writer.write(System.getProperty("line.separator") + "(" + id + ",'2020-" + month + "-" + day + 
                                "','" + times[k] + "','" + times[k+1] + "',0),");
                    }

                }catch(Exception o){
                    o.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

This gave me a file like this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Campo1;

CREATE TABLE `campo1` 
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,day date default NULL
,start_hour time default NULL
,end_hour time default NULL
,prenoted tinyint NOT NULL default 0
);

INSERT INTO campo1 VALUES

(1,'2020-01-01','00:00:00','00:01:00',0),
(2,'2020-01-01','00:01:00','00:02:00',0),
(3,'2020-01-01','00:02:00','00:03:00',0),
(4,'2020-01-01','00:03:00','00:04:00',0),
(5,'2020-01-01','00:04:00','00:05:00',0),
(6,'2020-01-01','00:05:00','00:06:00',0),
(7,'2020-01-01','00:06:00','00:07:00',0),
(8,'2020-01-01','00:07:00','00:08:00',0),
(9,'2020-01-01','00:08:00','00:09:00',0),
(10,'2020-01-01','00:09:00','00:10:00',0),
(11,'2020-01-01','00:10:00','00:11:00',0),
(12,'2020-01-01','00:11:00','00:12:00',0),
(13,'2020-01-01','00:12:00','00:13:00',0),
(14,'2020-01-01','00:13:00','00:14:00',0),
(15,'2020-01-01','00:14:00','00:15:00',0),
(16,'2020-01-01','00:15:00','00:16:00',0),
(17,'2020-01-01','00:16:00','00:17:00',0),
(18,'2020-01-01','00:17:00','00:18:00',0),
(19,'2020-01-01','00:18:00','00:19:00',0),
(20,'2020-01-01','00:19:00','00:20:00',0),
...
(8784,'2020-12-31','00:23:00','00:00:00',0);
```

I've imported the file in mysql's shell with:

```
 source filename.sql;
```

Then the answers to my questions are:

1)
I can change the prenoted field of the 10th id using:

```
UPDATE campo1 x JOIN (SELECT * FROM campo1 ORDER BY id LIMIT 9,1) y ON y.id = x.id SET x.prenoted = 1;
```

2)
I can see that it worked because mysql shell says:

```
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
                         ^^^
```

but also giving this command:

```
SELECT prenoted FROM campo1 ORDER BY id LIMIT 9,1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS campo1;

CREATE TABLE `campo1` 
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,day date default NULL
,start_hour time default NULL
,end_hour time default NULL
,prenoted tinyint NOT NULL default 0
);

INSERT INTO campo1 VALUES
( 1,'2020-01-01','00:00:00','01:00:00',0),
( 2,'2020-01-01','01:00:00','02:00:00',0),
( 3,'2020-01-01','02:00:00','03:00:00',0),
( 4,'2020-01-01','03:00:00','04:00:00',0),
( 5,'2020-01-01','04:00:00','05:00:00',0),
( 6,'2020-01-01','05:00:00','06:00:00',0),
( 7,'2020-01-01','06:00:00','07:00:00',0),
( 8,'2020-01-01','07:00:00','08:00:00',0),
( 9,'2020-01-01','08:00:00','09:00:00',0),
(10,'2020-01-01','09:00:00','10:00:00',0),
(11,'2020-01-01','10:00:00','11:00:00',0),
(12,'2020-01-01','11:00:00','12:00:00',0),
(13,'2020-01-01','12:00:00','13:00:00',0),
(14,'2020-01-01','13:00:00','14:00:00',0),
(15,'2020-01-01','14:00:00','15:00:00',0),
(16,'2020-01-01','15:00:00','16:00:00',0),
(17,'2020-01-01','16:00:00','17:00:00',0),
(18,'2020-01-01','17:00:00','18:00:00',0),
(19,'2020-01-01','18:00:00','19:00:00',0),
(20,'2020-01-01','19:00:00','20:00:00',0);

SELECT * FROM campo1 ORDER BY id;
+------+------------+------------+----------+----------+
| id   | day        | start_hour | end_hour | prenoted |
+------+------------+------------+----------+----------+
|    1 | 2020-01-01 | 00:00:00   | 01:00:00 |        0 |
|    2 | 2020-01-01 | 01:00:00   | 02:00:00 |        0 |
|    3 | 2020-01-01 | 02:00:00   | 03:00:00 |        0 |
|    4 | 2020-01-01 | 03:00:00   | 04:00:00 |        0 |
|    5 | 2020-01-01 | 04:00:00   | 05:00:00 |        0 |
|    6 | 2020-01-01 | 05:00:00   | 06:00:00 |        0 |
|    7 | 2020-01-01 | 06:00:00   | 07:00:00 |        0 |
|    8 | 2020-01-01 | 07:00:00   | 08:00:00 |        0 |
|    9 | 2020-01-01 | 08:00:00   | 09:00:00 |        0 |
|   10 | 2020-01-01 | 09:00:00   | 10:00:00 |        0 |
|   11 | 2020-01-01 | 10:00:00   | 11:00:00 |        0 |
|   12 | 2020-01-01 | 11:00:00   | 12:00:00 |        0 |
|   13 | 2020-01-01 | 12:00:00   | 13:00:00 |        0 |
|   14 | 2020-01-01 | 13:00:00   | 14:00:00 |        0 |
|   15 | 2020-01-01 | 14:00:00   | 15:00:00 |        0 |
|   16 | 2020-01-01 | 15:00:00   | 16:00:00 |        0 |
|   17 | 2020-01-01 | 16:00:00   | 17:00:00 |        0 |
|   18 | 2020-01-01 | 17:00:00   | 18:00:00 |        0 |
|   19 | 2020-01-01 | 18:00:00   | 19:00:00 |        0 |
|   20 | 2020-01-01 | 19:00:00   | 20:00:00 |        0 |
+------+------------+------------+----------+----------+

UPDATE campo1 x JOIN (SELECT * FROM campo1 ORDER BY id LIMIT 9,1) y ON y.id = x.id SET x.prenoted = 1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
                         ^^^ LOOK! A ROW WAS UPDATED!!!
SELECT * FROM campo1;
+----+------------+------------+----------+----------+
| id | day        | start_hour | end_hour | prenoted |
+----+------------+------------+----------+----------+
|  1 | 2020-01-01 | 00:00:00   | 01:00:00 |        0 |
|  2 | 2020-01-01 | 01:00:00   | 02:00:00 |        0 |
|  3 | 2020-01-01 | 02:00:00   | 03:00:00 |        0 |
|  4 | 2020-01-01 | 03:00:00   | 04:00:00 |        0 |
|  5 | 2020-01-01 | 04:00:00   | 05:00:00 |        0 |
|  6 | 2020-01-01 | 05:00:00   | 06:00:00 |        0 |
|  7 | 2020-01-01 | 06:00:00   | 07:00:00 |        0 |
|  8 | 2020-01-01 | 07:00:00   | 08:00:00 |        0 |
|  9 | 2020-01-01 | 08:00:00   | 09:00:00 |        0 |
| 10 | 2020-01-01 | 09:00:00   | 10:00:00 |        1 |
| 11 | 2020-01-01 | 10:00:00   | 11:00:00 |        0 |
| 12 | 2020-01-01 | 11:00:00   | 12:00:00 |        0 |
| 13 | 2020-01-01 | 12:00:00   | 13:00:00 |        0 |
| 14 | 2020-01-01 | 13:00:00   | 14:00:00 |        0 |
| 15 | 2020-01-01 | 14:00:00   | 15:00:00 |        0 |
| 16 | 2020-01-01 | 15:00:00   | 16:00:00 |        0 |
| 17 | 2020-01-01 | 16:00:00   | 17:00:00 |        0 |
| 18 | 2020-01-01 | 17:00:00   | 18:00:00 |        0 |
| 19 | 2020-01-01 | 18:00:00   | 19:00:00 |        0 |
| 20 | 2020-01-01 | 19:00:00   | 20:00:00 |        0 |
+----+------------+------------+----------+----------+

mysql> UPDATE campo1 x JOIN (SELECT * FROM campo1 ORDER BY id LIMIT 9,1) y ON y.id = x.id SET x.prenoted = 1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
                         ^^^ LOOK! NO ROW WAS UPDATED!!!
```

Comment: If I drop my table I'll have only one day, my actual table contains the whole year and I need the whole year

Comment: Is that observation in some way relevant?

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped me a lot!